# AR(1) process with exponential noise.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, finance, time-series

For the AR(1) process defined by $Z_t = aZ_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, $\epsilon_t \sim Exp(\lambda)$, $a \in (0,1),\lambda >0$, compute $P(Z_t|Z_{t-1})$.

I was only able to compute $E(Z_t|Z_{t-1}) = aZ_{t-1}+1/\lambda$ and $Var(Z_t|Z_{t-1})=1/\lambda^2$, but these are not enough for computing $P(Z_t|Z_{t-1})$. Can someone help me?

Comment: The conditional distribution of $Z_t|Z_{t-1}=z$ will just follows a shifted exponential distribution, with shift parameter $az$ and rate parameter $\lambda$ as usual.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to make it more clear. Do you actually mean $(Z_t|Z_{t-1}=k) = ak+\epsilon_t$ and from there $F_{Z_t|Z_{t-1}} = P(Z_t|Z_{t-1}<z_t) = P(\epsilon_t <z_t-ak) = F(z_t-ak)$, where F corresponds to the exponential CDF, so then $p_{Z_t|Z_{t-1}}(z) = \lambda e^{-\lambda(z-az_{t-1})}$ for z>=0 and 0 otherwise. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes. Just note that the support is shifted as well - now it will become $(az_{t-1}, +\infty)$